# I don't understand this from my lecture note. What is described by $x=X(\xi)$? Why $\xi(t)$ is a curve since $\xi \in R^{m-1}$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I don't understand this from my lecture note. What is described by $x=X(\xi)$? Why $\xi(t)$ is a curve since $\xi \in R^{m-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, an abuse of notation happened here. Let's see if illustration will help (honestly, I've tried to do my best to draw it as pleasantly as possible):

[image]

So, it's confusing that curve has the same name as it's codomain. What was really meant is that you can parameterize a patch of hypersurface with neighbourhood of euclidean space of lesser dimension (that's $x = X (\xi)$) and you can replace curve $u(t)$ with curve $v(t)$ using this parameterization by composition: $u(t) = X(v(t))$.

Hope this will make things clear.